# Why does Azure refuse web up from CLI with resource group "cannot be used with the os 'Windows" from Linux machine?

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-appservice

When trying to use the following command:
`az webapp up --sku F1 --name ap-name --resource-group my-rg --html`
from a Linux box, I get:

> The ResourceGroup 'my_rg' cannot be used with the os 'Windows'. Use a different RG.

The project is written in Python/Flask on Fedora.  There is a resource file available.  The resource group I specified is a Linux resource.  Nowhere is Windows involved in this project.

I can deploy to a Windows Resource group, but it obviously doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation page:

> Create a webapp and deploy code from a local workspace to the app. The
> command is required to run from the folder where the code is present.
> Current support includes Node, Python, .NET Core and ASP.NET. Node,
> Python apps are created as Linux apps. **.Net Core, ASP.NET, and static
> HTML apps are created as Windows apps**. Append the html flag to deploy
> as a static HTML app.

Have you tried specifying Linux as the OS type?

```
[--os-type {Linux, Windows}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  To no avail.  "unrecognized aruments: --os-type Linux".  Really baffling.

Comment: Not baffling, it simply confirms that static HTML apps are created as Windows apps only.  You can suggest a change using UserVoice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my AZ CLI and it worked.

```
az updgrade --yes
```

The I set the CLI to auto update.

```
az config set auto-upgrade.enable=yes
```